# Set default dropdown bindLabel in @ng-select/ng-select on self change event in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one scenario where i want to set default value to `null` in **ng-select**.
if user select dropdown first then on change event should check `Amount` model is not null or blank afterward if `Amount` model is blank then `ng-select` should be set to null

In Html component

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Amount"/><br/><br/>
<label>Your ng-select</label><br/>
<ng-select [items]="currencyList"
           bindLabel="name"
           bindValue="name"
           placeholder="Select Currency"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCurrency"
           (change)="onChangeDropdown()">
</ng-select><br/>
```

In typescript on change event function

```
onChangeDropdown(){
  if(this.Amount){

  }else{
    this.selectedCurrency = null;
    alert("enter amount first");
  }
}
```

here i have attach link : [link for dropdown example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-fbpmsl?file=app/app.component.ts)

Even i also tested in normal html select dropdown this also show me as same output above

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCurrency" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeDropdown()">
    <option>--Select Currency--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let c of currencyList" value="{{c.id}}">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

It's only working for the first time, when I select more then once it's not working. Why this showing still `INR` or other currency name on dropdown list?

Answer (score 1):

Change this.selectedCurrency value to undefined or empty string

```
onChangeDropdown(){
  if(this.Amount){

  }else{
    this.selectedCurrency = {};
    // or this.selectedCurrency = '';
    alert("enter amount first");
  }
}
```

Comment: check my stackblitz link this still showing text on dropdown i have set internally (in typescript) to model

Comment: Edit the code then refresh stackblitz and run again

Comment: Did u change this.selectedCurrency = undefined; in else condition

Comment: Yes, doesn't seems to be reflect in html

Comment: Ok its only working for the first time. let me check

Comment: have you checked at your end??