# Set default dropdown bindLabel in @ng-select/ng-select on self change event in Angular 5/6?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one scenario where i want to set default value to `null` from self change event on **ng-select**.
if user select dropdown first then on change event should check `Amount` model is not null or blank afterward if `Amount` model is blank then `ng-select` should be set to null.

> The dropdown is set to null works for the first time only.

In Html component

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Amount"/><br/><br/>
<label>Your ng-select</label><br/>
<ng-select [items]="currencyList"
           bindLabel="name"
           bindValue="name"
           placeholder="Select Currency"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCurrency"
           (change)="onChangeDropdown()">
</ng-select><br/>
```

In typescript on change event function

```
onChangeDropdown(){
  if(this.Amount){

  }else{
    this.selectedCurrency = null;
    alert("enter amount first");
  }
}
```

here i have attach link : [link for dropdown example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-fbpmsl?file=app/app.component.ts)

Even i also tested in normal html select dropdown this also show me as same output above

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCurrency" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeDropdown()">
    <option>--Select Currency--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let c of currencyList" value="{{c.id}}">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Why this showing still `INR` or other currency name on **ng-select**?

I have posted same question but not find right solution here [Set default dropdown bindLabel in @ng-select/ng-select on self change event in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52052990/9775003)??

Answer (score 0):

You are binding `ngSelect` by name.

```
bindLabel="name"
bindValue="name"
```

and the `selectedCurrency` is  the type any if you change

```
this.selectedCurrency = null; //to
this.selectedCurrency = {}; //it will work. just try this
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a setTimeOut to force Angular show the null value

```
onChangeDropdown(){
      if(this.Amount){
      }else{
        alert("enter amount first");
        setTimeout(()=>{
          this.selectedCurrency = null;
        },0)
      }
    }
```

Comment: I do not mind a downvote, but I'm curious to know the reason (i love learn), can anyone explain me what's wrong with the code?